# "not a known element" issue when trying to add ng-bootstrap in ng-seed/universal

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to add [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/) to [ng-seed/universal](https://github.com/ng-seed/universal/) by following  the steps on their README but I'm getting the ng-X component "is not a known element":

`'ngb-rating' is not a known element`

I tried adding a simple rating to the home component template:
https://github.com/ng-seed/universal/blob/master/src/client/app/+home/home.component.ts

In `/src/client/app/+home/home.component.ts`, I added in the template:

```
<ngb-rating></ngb-rating>
```

In `/src/client/app/app.module.ts`, I added and imported it:

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],  
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I tried importing the `NgbModule` module to the home `home.component.ts` but that didn't work either.

Stack trace:

```
[ERROR ->]<ngb-rating></ngb-rating>"): ng:///HomeModule/HomeComponent.html@1:2
    at Error (native)
    at syntaxError (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:76273:34)
    at TemplateParser.parse (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:86764:19)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:100515:39)
    at /temp/universal/.server/server.js:100439:62
    at Set.forEach (native)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:100439:19)
    at createResult (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:100324:19)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:72372:26)
    at Object.onInvoke (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:4717:37)
    at resolvePromise (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:72751:31)
    at resolvePromise (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:72722:17)
    at /temp/universal/.server/server.js:72799:17
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:72405:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:4708:37)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:72404:36)
    at Zone.runTask (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:72172:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:72565:35)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:72471:25)
    at data.args.(anonymous function) (/temp/universal/.server/server.js:73255:25)
```